# Method to check if the string contains certain elements that accepts a parameter String

Tags: java, string, methods, contains, startswith

I am a student and kind of new to Java. For my homework I have to:

- Ask the user to input a number (at least 7) using a do while loop.
- Using a for loop I am required to ask the user to input `that` number of words.
- Then I have to check if one of the words fulfills the given conditions:

*The word must:*

1. Start with an uppercase letter
2. End with a number
3. Contain the word "cse".

I am asked to create a method inside some code homework that does a specific task, the method should check all the required conditions, the name of the method should be `countTest` and *it accepts the String as a parameter*.

I will show you my code but I don't know how to create this specific method.

---

**Output format**

```
System.out.println("There as a total number of words " + count + " and 
the ones that fulfill the condition are: " + condition);
```

---

The problem is, I dont know how to create the method or constructor or whatever it is called that calls all of the 3 methods inside it, and then connect that particular method to the main method!
I hope you guys can understand I am new to this, thank you in advance!

[image]

````
public class D6_6 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a number that is at least 7");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        int condition = 0;
        do{
            if(number<7){
                System.out.println("You should type a number that is at least 7 or higher");
                number = sc.nextInt();
            }

        }
        while(number<7);
        sc.nextLine();
        String str;
        for(int i =0; i<number; i++){
            System.out.println("Type a word");
            str = sc.nextLine();
            count++;
        }
    }
    public boolean countTest(String str)    {

}```
````

Comment: *`charAt(int index)` can be used to obtain an character at a specified index.* A simple for loop can help you achieve what you want. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @AKSingh, I dont know how to create this Method or what to put in it so it can check all 3 of the conditions. Thats the issue, thanks for you reply.

Comment: @user15793316 Hi, sorry about that. You can check the code here: https://pastebin.com/7bdtJN4H . Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: Please post code not pictures. what have you tried yourself?

Comment: @user15793316 I really do understand but for some reason when I try to put my code in the text section, only half of it shows, the other half doesnt work.

Comment: @Ivonet Hi, thank you for your reply! I know the methods that I have to use for those conditions but I don't know how to creat like "public boolean countTest" method, that I can access and how to access it in the main method, that is my issue.

Comment: @user15793316 I edited it once, and I cannot edit it anymore for some reason:(

Comment: @user15793316 I think it is better now, I fixed it thank you. That is the code, I dont know how to create the method that call the three other methods and then I want to connect that to the main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To check if the word start with an uppercase:
   You can do that by first selecting the character you want to check by `str.charAt(0)`. This will return a char that is the first letter of the input `str`.
   To check if this char is an uppercase letter, you can easily use `char.isUppercase()`. This will return a boolean. You have to replace `char` by the name of the variable were you put the char of `str.charAt(0)` in.
2. To check if the last character is a number:
   You can do that again by first selecting the last character by `str.charAt(str.length()-1)`, were `string.length-1` is the number of the last character.
   To check if this character is a number, you can use the ascii table. Every character has it's own number. So if you want to check if your character is between 0 and 9, you can use `char >= 48 || char <= 57` (look up in the ascii table). Again, `char` is the name of the variable were you put the char of `str.charAt(str.length()-1)` in.
3. To check if the word contains "cse":
   There is a very easy method for that: `str.contains("cse")` will return a boolean that is true when "cse" is in the word and false when the word does not contain "cse".

I hope it is clear for you now!

Comment: Hi @Sven, thank you very very much for your reply and answer. When I do all of these I am confused on how do I access the method that I've created all of these conditions in the main method, thats my problem. My problem is the method, should it be a boolean or a String or idk? Then how do I connect it to the main method, to be exact inside the for loop. Thank you again!

Comment: @Eno I'm not sure what you want your output to be. Do you want something like: "The total number of words are 7 and the ones that fulfill the condition are: Scent9 Sce45"?

Comment: The output should be like this: The total number of words is 7 and the ones that fulfill the condition are: +condition(the ones that fulfill the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it, thank you guys very much, I appreciate it!

````
public class D6_6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a number that is at least 7");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        int condition = 0;
        do {
            if (number < 7) {
                System.out.println("You should type a number that is at least 7 or higher");
                number = sc.nextInt();
            }

        }
        while (number < 7);
        sc.nextLine();
        String str;
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            System.out.println("Type a word");
            str = sc.nextLine();
            count++;
            if((countTest(str))){
                condition++;

            }
        }
        if(count == 0){
            System.out.println("No words typed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Total number of words typed: " + count + ", which fulfill the condition: "+ condition);
        }
    }

    public static boolean countTest(String str) {
        return Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) && str.charAt(str.length() - 1) >= 48 || str.charAt(str.length() - 1) <= 57 || str.contains("cse");
    }

}```
````